# Which C++ standard library functions allocate memory?

Tags: c++11, std, misra

It's obvious that the collection classes with their `class Allocator = std::allocator<T>` parameter explicitly use heap allocations, but which other library functions (or indeed language features) can be expected to allocate memory in a practical implementation.

I know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45497684/1270789) that `throw` may be expected to (I don't have the spec to hand for the exact terminology) allocate memory for the stack trace, but where else may it occur?

---

**Background**: MISRA C++ 18-4-1 says "Dynamic heap allocation shall not be used", yet other rules cover the use of `throw` (15-0-1/2/3), and yet others (eg 3-4-1) have sample code using `std::cout` which I would expect to allocate memory.

Comment: regarding `std::cout` specifically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763488/c-how-do-streams-allocate-space-for-input. tl;dr `std::cout` does not allocate.